# Accessing Image Width Outside of onload with Javascript

Tags: javascript, image, callback, onload

I am trying to use a call back to determine if an images width is correct. It seems that when using an onload that it is impossible to do a return true or false.

Should this callback work to alleviate that issue? It seems that the onload event is never firing.

```
validateImageSize(function(imageWidth){
     alert(imageWidth);
});


function validateImageSize(callback) {

    imageFile = document.getElementById("filePath").files[0];
    imageFileUrl = window.URL.createObjectURL(imageFile);
    uploadedImage = new Image();

    uploadedImage.onload = function(){
        var imageWidth = uploadedImage.width;
        callback(imageWidth); 
    };

    uploadedImage.src = imageFileUrl;

};
```

Comment: Do it from the onload (you can call another function from there, and pass any needed data). It's an asynchronous event, you can't use `return`.

Comment: Thanks, I am able to pass the width outside of the onload to a different function. However my if statement in my check form function still always fails because i am never able to get a return back to my validImageSize function. Can I pass the width back to my validImageSize function?

Comment: There is no way, you simply can't return; you need to reestructure your code to deal with that.

Comment: Thanks for your replies, I am pretty new to this so pardon my lack of skill..

Comment: Hit enter on accident.. so would a callback be what I need to get this to work?

Comment: Yes! A callback like that should work.